# Error in matcaffe installation

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, caffe, matcaffe

[image]

The above error showed up when I tried to install matcaffe in ubuntu. I switched to caffe root directory, and ran the following commands:

```
$ cd /home/naved/Desktop/caffe-master
$ make all matcaffe
$ make mattest
```

My matlab version is 2011a.

After running `make mattest`, the error above showed up.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of errors, but copy and paste the error text into the question.

Comment: Did you try to download the framework from Matlab Central?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the functionality for custom unit test caffe(and specifically the package matlab.unittest.TestCase) was introduced in version `R2015a` of `MATLAB`, and that if you're on an older version it won't be available

Comment: You can download a Matlab XUnit test framework from http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47302-xunit4